# numpy mean and sum not permutable

Tags: python, numpy

I'm concerned about the fact that computing `np.mean(np.sum(x, axis=1))` does not give the same result as `np.sum(np.mean(x, axis=0))`.

For instance:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
x = np.random.randint(1000, 100)

sm = np.sum(np.mean(x, axis=0))
ms = np.mean(np.sum(x, axis=1))

print('sm {}'.format(sm))
print('ms {}'.format(ms))
print('sm == ms {}'.format(sm == ms))
```

prints

```
sm 0.1314820175147663
ms 0.13148201751476632
sm == ms False
```

Is this a `numpy` issue or am I missing something?

(obviously all types are equal in this calculation, `np.float64`; casting x to `np.float64` does not change anything)

Python 3.6.4, numpy 1.14.5

Comment: It can happen. Remember 0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3. Possible duplicate: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Probably it's just the residual error

Comment: I understand that but why does the order of operations matter? (editted to `randn` and not `randint`). I know 0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3 but I expected 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.2 + 0.1, to follow the comparison

Comment: @ted, You will get floating point vs decimal errors along the way when you combine multiple operations. There's nothing to say your floating point error will be identical whichever path you take. This is true for `float` generally, nothing Python / NumPy related.

Comment: Ok. So it's expected. Cheers!

Comment: if it is a problem you have `np.allclose` and `np.isclose` to test near-equality

Comment: Yeah I had that but thanks :)